# Can I still update my free apps if I change my iTunes Account Country?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, ios-appstore, accounts

If I change my iTunes Acccount country, I realize that I'll lose the ability to update apps for which I've paid.
But what about apps that were freely purchased like : Facebook, Twitter, ... Will they still get updates ?

Answer (score 1):

Since they're free, just re-download them. You can update them on your iOS device, but it's a bit of a problem since you need to switch accounts, and you can only do that once every 90 days. You won't be able to update them in iTunes, however, when you switch countries.