# Managing to change my Apple ID to another country

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, apple-id

I need to change the country of Apple ID from UK to US, but I previously purchased some apps with my UK-based account, do I need to re-purchase them after migration? Will I still be updating my apps after changing the country?

Thanks!

Comment: It's fairly well documented that when you change your store, you leave behind all purchases - both free and paid, but if you can edit your question to explain how it's not a duplicate of other questions here, feel free to flag it for a review and we should have no issues with reopening it.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80528/restoring-past-purchases-from-different-country?rq=1

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83771/can-i-still-update-my-free-apps-if-i-change-my-itunes-account-country?rq=1